# htaccess, redirect all requests to splash.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to put up a splash page for a site relaunch. All requests need to redirect to `splash.php` ... but this file needs access to the the `/splash` directory which contains an image used within the splash page.

I'm not sure what the exact rules need to be within `htaccess` ... also, would it be better if all requests were routed to `/splash` and the actual splash page was an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(image\.png)$
RewriteRule (.*)  /splash.html [QSA]
```

Should at least give you a starting point...

Comment: What happens when you try it? I should have qualified that I hadn't tested it (which I thought was implied with 'Something along the lines of' :))

Answer (score 0):

I found a great script here on SO:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.89
RewriteRule index.php$ /splash.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Note that this will only redirect requests to `index.php`, not to __any__ file like you imply you want